# Subir HTML, CSS e imagenes a un WordPress

Tags: html5, wordpress

He realizado un landing page en HTML. También hay un documento CSS y las imágenes correspondientes.
Ando mirando la manera de incluir estos documentos externos en WordPress pero lo que veo es editar el HTML o crear una página en el propio CMS.

¿Hay alguna manera de subir o incluir estos archivos externos? Me gustaría añadir esta página y marcarla como index para que sea el landing.

Comment: Tendrás que crear un custom theme o crear un child theme, dentro crear un archivo tipo landing.php y asignarlo como plantilla de pagina, agregar tu html y encolar los archivos css y js desde tu functions, es un tema algo extenso asi que tendrás que investigar un poco por tu cuenta, puedes leer la documentación para tener una mejor idea de como hacerlo https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development.

Comment: O puedes dejar a WordPress como secundario y luego desde tu landing entrar a las secciones de tu WP que quieras por medio de links. Yo hice eso con un cliente.